# Get system username in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore

Is there any cross platform way to get the current username in a Qt C++ program?

I've crawled the internet and the documentation for a solution, but the only thing I find are OS dependent system calls.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I was actually thinking about it a couple of days ago, and I came to the conclusion of having different alternatives, each with its own trade-off, namely:

### Environment variables using [qgetenv](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qtglobal.html#qgetenv).

The advantage of this solution would be that it is really easy to implement. The drawback is that if the environment variable is set to something else, this solution is completely unreliable then.

```
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    QString name = qgetenv("USER");
    if (name.isEmpty())
        name = qgetenv("USERNAME");
    qDebug() << name;
    return 0;
}
```

### Home location with [QStandardPaths](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qstandardpaths.html)

The advantage is that, it is relatively easy to implement, but then again, it can go unreliable easily since it is valid to use different username and "entry" in the user home location.

```
#include <QStandardPaths>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDir>

int main()
{
    QStringList homePath = QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::HomeLocation);
    qDebug() << homePath.first().split(QDir::separator()).last();
    return 0;
}
```

### Run external processes and use platform specific APIs

This is probably the most difficult to implement, but on the other hand, this seems to be the most reliable as it cannot be changed under the application so easily like with the environment variable or home location tricks. On Linux, you would use [QProcess](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qprocess.html) to invoke the usual [whoami command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whoami), and on Windows, you would use the [GetUserName WinAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms724432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for this purpose.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
// Strictly pseudo code!
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
    char acUserName[MAX_USERNAME];
    DWORD nUserName = sizeof(acUserName);
    if (GetUserName(acUserName, &nUserName))
        qDebug << acUserName;
    return 0;
#elif Q_OS_UNIX
    QCoreApplication coreApplication(argc, argv);
    QProcess process;
    QObject::connect(&process, &QProcess::finished, [&coreApplication, &process](int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus) {
        qDebug() << process.readAllStandardOutput();
        coreApplication.quit();
    });
    process.start("whoami");
    return coreApplication.exec();
#endif
}
```

*Summary*: I would personally go for the last variant since, even though it is the most difficult to implement, that is the most reliable.

Comment: your first "if" is with upper case.

Comment: I didn't downvote it, I tried to edit, but it was a too short of an edit and SOF didn't accept it. I actually like your answer, thank you.

Comment: @migas: thanks, my answer got downvoted to -1 initially, and I just cannot understand why when I put the most effort into answering it IMHO. It is a useful knowledge for SO though. Thanks for asking it. :-)

Comment: Hats off, more than I could ask for. Due to the nature of my program and the controlled environment it will run in, I'll opt for the `qgetenv` option for its simplicity. The option of the home environment is, IMHO, not actually an option, since home is where the heart is (or where the user defines it to be). But for the quality of the answer it is definitely approved. For the record, I didn't test neither the second nor the third solutions but they surely seem legit.

Comment: @migas: in the last example, the finished() signal sadly needs explicit overload resolution, but I will leave that with the reader as a finger exercise. :-)

Comment: @lpap on Linux you would use QProcess and whoami? I would not. I would use the getlogin_r function. ;-)

Comment: [GetUserName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms724432.aspx) has a Unicode version (`GetUserNameW`), which you should be using. Using the ANSI version `GetUserNameA` needlessly wastes resources, and can fail to produce the desired result.

Answer (score 7):

There is no way to get the current username with Qt.

However, you can read this links :

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/12965-Get-user-name
http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/11951

I think the best method is :

```
#include <stdlib.h>

getenv("USER"); ///for MAc or Linux
getenv("USERNAME"); //for windows
```

EDIT : You can use `qgetenv` instead of `getenv`.

Comment: If I'd use environment variables I think I'd prefer to use `qgetenv` since it is the Qt way to do it.

Comment: @migas: not only that, it is also unreliable.

Comment: I think `qgetenv` is better than `getenv` too. :)

Answer (score 3):

In QT5 and up it is possible to do the following :

```
QString userName = QDir::home().dirName();
```

`[QDir::home()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#home) returns the user's home directory.

Comment: Important to note that the user home directory is not always the same as username.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [qEnvironmentVariable](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qEnvironmentVariable)

```
QString sysUsername = qEnvironmentVariable("USER");
if (sysUsername.isEmpty()) sysUsername = qEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME");
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [QProcessEnvironment](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocessenvironment.html) like this:

```
QProcessEnvironmentenv = QProcessEnvironment::systemEnviroment();
QString username = env.value("USER");
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to get the current windows username with Qt. Here it is

**mainwindow.ui**
[This is the form ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLhXu.png)

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDir>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->getUser();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::getUser()
{
    QProcess *username = new QProcess();
    QStringList cmdParamaters, split;
    QString clean1, clean2, clean3,userName;
    int cutOff, strLen;

    cmdParamaters << "/c"<<"\"%USERPROFILE%\"";
    username->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
    username->start("cmd.exe",cmdParamaters);
    username->waitForFinished();

    QString vusername (username->readAllStandardOutput());
    cutOff = vusername.indexOf("'", 1);
    ui->label_2->setText(vusername);

    clean1 = vusername.left(cutOff);
    ui->label_3->setText(clean1);

    clean2 = clean1.remove(0,3);
    strLen = clean2.length();
    ui->label_4->setText(clean2);

    clean3 = clean2.left(strLen-2);
    split = clean3.split("\\");

    userName = split[2]; //This is the current system username
    ui->label_5->setText(userName);
    delete username;
}
```

**Output:**
[Code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLhXu.png)